# Using SilverStripe's SQLQuery object without selecting * fields

Tags: orm, silverstripe

Looking [at the documentation](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/sql_query/), there are fairly good instructions on how to build up a SQL query.

My code looks like this:

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLQuery();
$sqlQuery->setFrom('PropertyPage')->selectField('PropertyType')->setDistinct(true);
```

I'm aiming to get the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyType FROM PropertyPage
```

but instead I'm getting back this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, PropertyType FROM PropertyPage
```

Even their own example seems to give back a 'SELECT DISTINCT *. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you use SQLQuery directly?

With pure ORM it should go like this:

```
$result = PropertyPage::get()->setQueriedColumns(array('PropertyType'))->distinct();
```

which returns a DataList you can loop over.

See [setQueriedColumns()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_setQueriedColumns) and [distinct()](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html#_distinct)

What version of SS framework are you using? Distinct was added in 3.1.7 iirc.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to @wmk's answer as well as directly address how to do it with `SQLQuery`, your call to `selectField` is the reason why that query happened. The [documentation to `selectField`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SQLQuery.html#_selectField) shows that it adds an additional field to select, not restrict the list to just that field.

The reason why their examples ([A](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/sql_query/#select) and [B](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/model/sql_query/#joins)) also had the issue is that [the first parameter for the constructor for `SQLQuery` is a default value of "*" for select statement](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SQLQuery.html#___construct).

To still use your code as a base, replace your use of `selectField` with [`setSelect`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-SQLQuery.html#_setSelect). Your query will then look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT PropertyType FROM PropertyPage
```

It isn't bad to directly query the database using `SQLQuery` especially if you really just want the raw data of a particular column or the result itself cannot be expressed against a `DataObject` (eg. using column aliases). You would also have a small performance improvement that PHP would not have to instantiate a `DataObject`.

While saying that, it can be far more useful having a `DataObject` and the various functions that it exposes per record.